# Distracting popup window that appears when writing a question?

Tags: support

I have just noted that when writing a technical [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71056/2751) on the main page, a blue popup window appears telling me that the question I am writing is too subjective and will probably be closed.

What distracting nonsense is this? Can this unneeded new feature be turned of on Physics SE? At least should the algorithm used to recognize inappropriate questions while they are written be debugged, such that it is not triggered when people are for example writing technical questions.

People on sites like MathOverflow, CS Theory, etc will not be happy about such new features too I guess

Comment: At least tell us what the contents of the question are.

Comment: @Manishearth done. And yes this quite annoys me because there is absolutely nothing subjective about my question and I expect technical answers ...

Comment: It's not calling your question subjective. It's saying that your question _looks_ subjective. If it isn't, ignore it. No need to get so worked up.

Comment: As I understand it, that pop-up runs off of some fairly stupid rules. Looking subjective to a minimal rule based system isn't necessarily a big deal.

Comment: Why would someone (2 people) downvote this? Having a robot that tells everyone something equivalent to "Stop writing" is completely useless! +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across it a couple of times too -- it has very few false alarms, and usually comes up when you *are* asking for opinions (Type "what do you think" in the topbar). I don't see why it's so annoying, it has a very useful feature and the couple of times you come across it, you can check your question for subjectiveness and *then* post it.

It's not a new feature. It's always been there, afaict. The fact that you, a user who has asked 80-odd questions, have *just* noticed it is testament to it not having too many false alarms.

And I doubt it will be turned off because it is extremely good at catching subjective questions (at least, ones I can come up with to test against it)

Remember, it's saying this (it's *not* calling your question as "too subjective"):

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed

It's a "maybe" statement, and all it's saying is that there's a chance that the question is subjective. It basically tells newbies that subjective questions are disallowed -- many don't know about that. If you think your question isn't subjective, go ahead and post it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for these explanations it is the first time I saw this ... Are there some other consequences that go along with the poping up of the window, as for example an automated flag?

Comment: @Dilaton Nope. It's a reminder, that's all. Basically, it's saying "Subjective questions aren't allowed here", so someone who doesn't know that will realize, check the question, and not post if it is subjective. There's no flag, but I don't see what the problem would be even if there is? In the case of questions like yours the automated flag (if it existed) would just be dismissed